# getElementById Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just kind of learning Javascript was following this exercise but it's not working and I don't understand. The page should read Some more text when loaded. But it's only show Some text from the paragraph. It not changing over with the getElementById like it should. Any tips?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


 <title>Learning Javascript</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



</head>

<body>

    <p id="text">Some text</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // This is a comment
    /* Multi line comment

    */

    document.getElementById{"text"}.innerHTML="Some more text";

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo: When calling a function, use parenthesis rather than braces - `document.getElementById("text")...`

Comment: because `getElementById{"text"}` is a syntax error and you should use `()` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using curly braces where you should be using parentheses.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Some more text";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Some more text";
```

You have the wrong type of brackets. Use `()`

Comment: Thanks don't know how I missed that.